# Unable to download Pellet plugin for Protege 4.3

Tags: protege4, pellet

I wish to add the Pellet reasoner plugin to Protege 4.3. To do so I go to *File-> Preferences -> Plugins -> Check for Downloads Now*. However, I cannot find the Pellet reasoner plugin in there.

I wished to have the Pellet reasoner since I wanted to add some SWRL rules containing SWRL math built ins (e.g. swrlb:mod built in). Furthermore, with HermiT reasoner 1.3.8 there is an error that the provided built in atom is not supported.

Please help me with this issue, as I am new to Protege.

Comment: Did you find a solution?

Comment: @gsamaras Not quite. I found some jars here mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.github.ansell.pellet., and used them directly inside the Java code with OWL API. Although, in Protege, I had to manage somehow with HermiT reasoner, by avoiding complicated SWRL rules. Unfortunately by the time the answers came, I was already done with the project so I didn't really check if any of those work.

Comment: I believe that should do it. However, presently I cannot personally test that solution. I will mark it as answered with a link to your question. Thanks !

Comment: Good idea! However, it would nice that you asked, that's why I upvoted your question, thanks again.

Answer (score 2):

**Pellet** is now located on GitHub. The repository file needs updating to point to it.

The code for **Pellet Protégé** plugin and the latest plugin jar is in
github now [1]. If you change the plugin registry location in **Protégé**
to point to [2] you should be able to install the **Pellet** plugin. The
link in the main **Protégé** plugin registry will be updated soon after
which things should work with default settings.

`File ==> Preference ==> Plugins` (add this URL and ) hit check for downloads now

https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Complexible/pellet/master/protege/plugin/plugins.repository

Source: https://github.com/protegeproject/autoupdate/issues/3

Comment: **THIS DOES NOT WORK**!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!! I copypasted the second link to Plugins, but got the very same results!

Comment: Works fine!!!!!

Answer (score 1):

**UPDATE:** Download Protegé Version 4.2 with the working Pellet plugin at https://github.com/nblavoie/protege-4.2-missing-pellet-plugin.

I have the same issue. The problem is the following. In Protegé, whatever the version, the plugin registry points to the following URL: http://protege.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/autoupdate/4_2/4.2-plugins-2012-03-19.repository.

If you check the Pellet URL http://clarkparsia.com/pellet/protege-4.1-beta/plugin/update.properties, there is a redirect to their Github page. No link to the JAR file for people like you and me that can't build the plugin.

I've contacted them and I'm also waiting for an answer/solution to the problem.

I've also tested the beta version 5.0 and the plugin isn't avaiable in the repo too.

I'll keep you updated when I hear feedback from them.

Comment: Perhaps for the moment I can use the Protege 4.2, you provided. However you are right about the Pellet URL being redirected to their github page. I kind of needed the Pellet .jar to use with OWL API code in Java. Luckily, I found some jars here http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.github.ansell.pellet., which works for me at the moment.

Thank you for your support :)

Comment: No problem. The issue has been raised on the Protegé mailing list at http://protege-project.136.n4.nabble.com/pellet-for-protege-4-or-later-td4662724.html.

Comment: The github link is an 404! Did you find a solution?

Comment: @scorpGoku i am trying to find pellet jars in the link  you provided , but i see no jar file to download . would you please guide me?

Comment: I'm not sure if the link or the jars still work but you may try this link: http://central.maven.org/maven2/com/github/ansell/pellet/pellet-common/2.3.6-ansell/. I got here by clicking "central" in front of repository on this page: http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.github.ansell.pellet/pellet-common/2.3.6-ansell . Hope this helps. Cheers!