# How to enable Pellet in Protege 4.3.0?

Tags: rdf, owl, protege, protege4, pellet

It's almost a year since [Unable to download Pellet plugin for Protege 4.3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29710154/unable-to-download-pellet-plugin-for-protege-4-3) suggested that it's not available for this version. Has anything changed?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It should be possible to download it from their github and just drop it into Progégé's plugins folder:
https://github.com/Complexible/pellet/raw/master/protege/plugin/com.clarkparsia.protege.plugin.pellet.jar

Comment: Thanks Victor. It has Pellet and Pellet (incremental). Which ones should I use? I want to make a simple school assignment.

Comment: Use Pellet - the incremental version has been reported to have a few bugs, so I would wait for a new Pellet release (post 2.3-2.4 version number) before using the incremental feature.